# Derby databse: Select all entries where timestamp is not set

Tags: sql, derby

using the derby DB how do I check if a field with the value timestamp has not been set?

I tried to check if it is null and if  is an empty String but none of those worked.

```
SELECT uid FROM APP.requests WHERE timestamp = null; 
SELECT uid FROM APP.requests WHERE timestamp = '';
```

While the first statement failed because there seems to exist no null value the 2nd one returns 0 rows.

How do I form an SQL statement that returns all rows where the timestamp field has not been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT uid FROM APP.requests WHERE timestamp is null;
```

It's not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as

```
=, <, or <>
```

You must use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I will accept your answer once the timer has run off. Thank you!